# Manually upgrade Magisk on Samsung Galaxy S10 without losing data

Tags: samsung, root-access, updates, magisk

I had a working Samsung Galaxy S10 which was already rooted with Magisk (v20.*). Due to a Magisk update (v24.1), my root got broken... So I need the manual way.

I successfully patched the stock "recovery.img" through the Magisk "Select and Patch a file" method since the "Direct Install" is not working anymore for some reason I don't understand ("Installation Failed. Unable to detect target image"). The official website recommends flashing the "recovery.img" through "fastboot". But then I discovered fastboot is not available for Samsung phones. So I need to use Odin. But Odin is not accepting *.img files.

I do not want to lose my current Android installation because it's very customised. But I need my root back. I searched and searched for days for a working solution to manage this. So this request is my last hope as I can really not find a way to manage this.

How can I safely flash this "magisk_patched" "recovery.img" to my "Samsung S10" without wiping any data? And does this Magisk patched "recovery.img" contain my existing TWRP recovery? Or do I need to reinstall it after the upgrade? I remember when I first rooted my phone, it was quite complicated to do this since the Samsung Galaxy S10 does not have a ramdisk, so the recovery partition is shared with TWRP and the Magisk su.

Does anyone have any good advice on how to manage this without losing my data (and Android 10 installation)? Magisk delivered me a 6.2GB "magisk_patched-24300_8m9cQ.tar" file, but I'm scared to flash it through Odin as I don't want to lose my data on my "512GB SD card" internal storage.

I know this is a complicated situation but any help would be highly appreciated as I really don't know what to do anymore to manage this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135073/discussion-on-question-by-kleajmp-manually-upgrade-magisk-on-samsung-s10-without).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some great help from @alecxs I managed to fix the problem, without losing any data, all the googled tutorials tell to use fastboot, which is not available for Samsung devices, so this is the guide for `Samsung S10` users who have a working twrp recovery installed but are unable to preform the automatic update from within the Magisk Manager app. (of course you need adb and developer mode enabled on your phone)

- first of all, for just in case, make a backup of all your partitions in twrp, also make a backup of your personal data stored in /sdcard
- in twrp, use the following adb commands to get an image from boot, recovery and vbmeta partitions from a terminal window on your computer:

  `adb pull /dev/block/platform/13d60000.ufs/by-name/boot *:\Magisk\Unpatched\boot.img`

  `adb pull /dev/block/platform/13d60000.ufs/by-name/recovery *:\Magisk\Unpatched\recovery.img`

  `adb pull /dev/block/platform/13d60000.ufs/by-name/vbmeta *:\Magisk\Unpatched\vbmeta.img`
- make a `tar` archive of these 3 images (you can use 7zip for this)
- boot back into Android, transfer the tar to your phone, start MagiskManager, next to Magisk, tap Install... with Options, be sure `Recovery Mode` is checked (since Magisk on Samsung S10 starts it deamon trough recovery as there is no ramdisk), tap Next, `Select and Patch a File`, select the tar, and let Magisc do its Magic.
- check the log file, if it says: `Magisk patched boot image detected` you're good to go...
- go find the `magisk_patched*.tar` in your ~/Download, copy it to your computer, extract the tarred images to a folder on your computer, for example: `*:\Magisk\Patched\`, remove the '.img' suffix from the three image files as adb can only manage them without the '.img' suffix!
- boot back into twrp recovery, connect your phone trough usb and transfer the MagiskPatched images back to your phone trough the following adb commands:

  `adb push *:\Magisk\Patched\boot /dev/block/platform/13d60000.ufs/by-name/boot`

  `adb push *:\Magisk\Patched\recovery /dev/block/platform/13d60000.ufs/by-name/recovery`

  `adb push *:\Magisk\Patched\vbmeta /dev/block/platform/13d60000.ufs/by-name/vbmeta`
- now, very important, delete the old Magisk configuration by removing the /data/adb directory, from within twrp terminal: `rm -r /data/adb`
- wipe the cache partition from the twrp gui (advanced wipe)
- boot back into Android and start the Magisk Manager app, it will tell you it needs to do some additional configuration and reboot your device... (if this step gives an error you did not succesfully delete the /data/adb folder)
- once your device is rebooted, you'll have your root back!
- have a good bottle of wine and reconfigure your Magisk settings/modules in Magisk Manager.
- enjoy to be the owner of your own device again!

Comment: Hey I have the exact same problem. Same phone I also get the "patched boot image detected" when I backed up the "boot.emmc.win" 64mb image with twrp.... So then.... can I flash the that patched boot image with twrp into.... will it be the boot partition and will it work of I remove the old magisk data in twrp? Or am I gonna get a bootloop? That part scares me-i backed up my rom with twrpbut in unsure if its enough